# VBA - How to fill the data to specific column by referred to another column on the same sheet

Tags: vba, excel

How can I automatically fill data into a specific column by referring to a different source-column on the same sheet?

**Example:**

In the source column are the numbers 1 to 10. How can I convert this into e.g. having "1" displayed as "One" in the second column?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Without knowing more about what you want to do, it is hard to help you. If it is just changing numbers into their literals, I think the best solution would be to create an array storing what each should be changed into, and then looping through the range you use as your source, using the values there to select the indices of your array. But again, hard to tell what you need to do from your description - some clarification would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to spell the number in the first column, then:-

1. Setup your column headers and format the area as a table (From Ribbon -> "Home" => "Format as Table").
2. Using the instructions from this Microsoft Support article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213360/en-us), add the code from the article into a VBA Module in the workbook.
3. Assuming your first data cell is "A2", add this formula to cell "B2":- `=SpellNumber(A2)`.  Since it is a table, the formula will be propagated down that entire column automatically, even when adding new rows.

You will need to modify the code from the MS Support article, as it is designed for returning Dollars & Cents phrases.

Answer (score 0):

without know that you really want, You can see [convert a numeric value into English words in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213360)

PS: joehanna sorry, I'm not saw your answer

Comment: No worries :) gotta be quick on SO!